# Browser comparability?

Tags: css, html, browser

I created a website,now i want to check the comparability issues,My website  is in html5

Is it necessary to check all browsers?What are the browsers i want to check?

Like chrome all versions,IE all versions etc .

Comment: Try http://browsershots.org/ with the default settings, but I usually just test the most recent Chrome and Firefox, then Firefox 3, then IE down to 7.

Comment: The W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org/) will be your friend here. Perhaps do a search on Google / Bing and find out the market share for the major browser versions.

Comment: I have the latest Chrome, IE, and Firefox installed on my machine and just open up the site in each and make sure it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the links, as a beginner its really going to help me

Comment: To test interactive web pages, browsershots is insufficient (because only screenshots are taken). An alternative is http://browserstack.com/, which offers a 30 minute free trial to test web pages in any browser (from the cloud). Although it works, I recommend to not use it if you're seriously going to test your web pages. The best way to test web pages is by installing the browsers on your own (virtual) machine. See my profile for the question "Cross-browser testing: All major browsers on ONE machine" if you want to spend 1-2 hours on setting up such an environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with html5 technologies different browsers impliment different subsets of the features. May I suggest [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/). This site will tell you what features are supported on what browsers.

In terms of testing, just fire up your website on the big 3 (chrome, firefox ie.) and also safari and opera if you want to. Check if the site looks and runs as expected.

Comment: I would also add lynx - That is what the search engines see (and also screen readers for the blind)

Comment: One more doubt,my outer div width is 1024px; is there any problem for that,or i should give some media queries like max-width:1024

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was what you are looking for :-P. And I very rarely ever set the `max-width` on pages unless I have a good reason.